# "Explain someone something" correct or wrong?

Tags: word-usage

I always thought that it is "explain something to someone". However, today I encountered a novel usage from the following snippet: "In response, Accardo asked someone to "explain him the facts of life. And I mean life." Giancana, however, remained adamant and refused to pay.".

I'm conflicted on taking this expression as correct because Accardo is essentially a mobster and is not the literate type. But was he correct?

Comment: In this case, I think we could say that the "wiseguy" was not such a wise guy. _Explain_ is not a ditransitive verb, so it should not have a moveable indirect object.

Comment: Where is the snippet from? It looks to me as though it's from a novel about the American Mafia. Am I right?

Comment: "Explain me this" and it's variants is fairly common slang in the US.

Comment: As I thought...it is [Sam Giancona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Giancana) . The book is ["Double cross"](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=Em6CDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22In+response,+Accardo+asked+someone+to+%22explain+him+the+facts+of+life.+And+I+mean+life.%22+Giancana,+however,+remained+adamant+and+refused+to+pay.%22.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfwOSai-vkAhVHx1kKHWePDHUQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) . It is not a "novel". It is an "insider" testimony. //On second thought, maybe this is worth a chew...

Answer (score 3):

> If you mention a person after **explain**, you always use **to**

Longman Dictionary of Common Errors

Comment: A rule to fix a common 'error' in a grammar book could mean that 1) it is an remark for foreign language learners that it is a pattern that isn't regular or 2) it is a common performance error and is not intended, or 3) it could mean that it is a common alternative for native speakers and is just not recognized as standard or is regional dialect or stylists just don't like it.

Comment: @Mitch I like that (what you said, I mean) . Really have to sleep on it though. It is very relevant for what is happening on EL&U.meta